# Is socket.io's "on" method an adder or setter?

Tags: javascript, socket.io, observer-pattern

In socket.io, will using "on" twice replace the older registration or will the event fire both listeners? Is it a generally consistent behavior with javascript "on" methods in general? And is there a reason there is no socket.io documentation for this?

```
var socket = io.connect("host:port")
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('listener1');
}

socket.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('listener2');
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no `on` method. Libraries just implement this as part of an Event Emitter/Pub-Sub pattern, where code "listens" from other code.

And no, it will not replace the existing registrations. They get added into a "queue". Think of it as this: It's not only one piece of code that listens for data to arrive. There could be hundreds of lines listening for that same data.

Comment: Thank you for the remark about EventEmitter. I forgot to ask how I would unregister listeners if the behavior was indeed additive. I found the removeListener method on the EventEmitter documentation. I presume the method will be implemented in socket.io as well.

Comment: @DylanP there is a removal process as well. jQuery has `unbind`, `off`, `undelegate`. NodeJS has `removeListener`. They should have similar implementations.